# Finding the Header Block in the Proteus symbol library

Tags: proteus

As the manual says...

> It is common practice to have on each sheet of a drawing a header
>   block which shows details such as the design and sheet titles, the
>   document, revision and page numbers, and the design's author. In order
>   that you have full control over how this information is presented, the
>   header block is defined as a symbol library entry called HEADER.

...but where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eeeeeeeeeeeasy. It only took me four hours to find it originally!

Within a design sheet select "2D Graphics Symbol Mode" - the icon is an 'S' in a green box, next to the line/rectangle/circle graphics. Either click the P at the top of the (currently empty) list box or double click in the box itself. This opens the Pick Symbols window. HEADER is found in the SYSTEM library, between DPST_1 and INVERTER (not that I'm questioning your spelling ability). Double click header then ESC or close the Pick Symbols window.

Place a Header somewhere on the sheet. You can't edit the default header so you have make your own. You can, in fact, make your own from scratch without doing any of what I said above, but it's a bit easier to start somewhere. Right click on the header and then DECOMPOSE. This will break the header into its constituent parts. Create, destroy, add rude words, do what you like (you've seen the table in the Help files following your quoted text for the '@' keywords). When you're happy with your new header, highlight the whole thing, right click then select MAKE SYMBOL. Give it a name and you're finished.

To get it back you find it in the USERSYM library, not the SYSTEM library.

Comment: Thanks - I have managed to make a new HEADER and use it. How do I get rid of the old one? I cannot select it.

Comment: You can't delete it from the library without a "DOS based library tool" or whatever Proteus call it. I've never bothered with modifying core libs because it's probably more hassle than it's worth. But if you're talking about getting rid of a header from a layout - again you can't. You have to make your own _template_.

Comment: What a hassle...

Comment: What I have done is just lay the new header over the old one. A bodge, but visually it works

Comment: Yes it's a hassle, but the point of a template is that you only have to spend an hour doing it once, then it's there every time you need it with one click of a button.

Comment: Except I am well into the circuit design schematics now

Comment: At least you'll know for next time!

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I have spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out before coming across this! I used to do it manually for each design with simple lines for borders and text I put in each time I did a new design. Was a pain in the a** so I wanted to standardise my designs by creating a custom header. They really do make it difficult to find information on it!